# PUT request giving 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: java, put, google-contacts-api, bad-request

I'm implementing a Contact application using `Google Contact API`.
Now I'm trying to update a contact by sending a put request in the below format

```
PUT /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/{contactId}
If-Match: {lastKnownEtag}
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
```

And I have the XML as a string that I'm going to send as a body of the request. 
This is my xmlString (**Body of the Request**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="*">
<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/1785xxxx</id>
<catagory scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
<gd:name>
<gd:fullname>abc</gd:fullname></gd:name>
<gd:email address="abc@gmail.com" displayName="abc" primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"/>
<content type="text">Notes</content>
<gd:phoneNumber primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other">9090xxxxxx</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
```

I have written the below code to send a PUT request to Update a Contact .

```
    String getUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/"+contactID+"?oauth_token=" + accessToken;         
    URL url = new URL(getUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();        
    con.setDoOutput(true);          
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml" );
    con.setRequestProperty("GData-Version","3.0"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("IF-MATCH", "*");
    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());      
    output.write(xmlString);   
    // xmlString is the body of the request
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

When I tried to send the request in `OAuth 2.0 Playground` , the contact is updated successfully.
But when I try to run the above program I'm getting

> 400 Bad Request Error

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: well what is the request. please use a proxy or so to show what it is. I bet xmlString is empty or invalid or so

Comment: @Daij-Djan I tried to send the same xmlString in Google Playground  and obtained the response as 200 OK. So there is no problem in the xmlString.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have added my xmlString as well . Please tell me if my string is invalid.

Comment: Where is the body of the request?

Comment: @noogui xmlString is body of the request. I have mentioned that in the post and I have given the xmlString also.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but is that how Google wants the oauth2 token, as a request parameter? Other APIs I've used expect a bearer token in a request header.

Comment: Also, it's `If-Match`, not `IF-MATCH`.

Comment: Thanks for responding.I found where I'm wrong. My xmlString requires another namespace which is not provided in Google Contact API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I have found where I'm going wrong.

My xmlString invalid. `<entry>` tag requires another namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` which is not mentioned in https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3 (**Google Contact API**).
That's the reason why I got 400 Bad request error.

Valid xmlString

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="*" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/1785xxxx </id>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
    <gd:name>
        <gd:fullName>name</gd:fullName>
    </gd:name>
    <gd:email address="juli@gmail.com" displayName="juli" primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" />
    <content type="text">Notes</content>
    <gd:phoneNumber primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other">9090xxxxxx</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
```