# How to set prefix for the attribute in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I like to set prefix for attribute while creating `XML` file using `Java`.
The result that I needed is

```
<entry gd:etag="*">
    <id>Text</id>
</entry>
```

But I'm getting

```
<entry etag="*">
    <id>Text</id>
</entry>
```

The code that I have written is

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuildFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element entry = doc.createElement("entry");
entry.setAttribute("etag","*");
doc.appendChild(entry);
Element id = doc.createElement("id");
id.setTextContent("Text");
entry.appendChild(id);
.....
```

I have no idea how to set prefix for the attributes. Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: you can use JAXB.Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) is a library that helps bind XML schemas and Java representations. JAXB provides you with a mechanism to marshal Java objects into XML and the other way around – unmarshal XML into Java objects.

Comment: Is the namespace for that prefix set anywhere? Is `<entry/>` the root node?

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes. <entry> is the root node. No namespace for that prefix set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DocumentBuilderFactory` to be namespace aware, and you need to set the namespace for that prefix and use `setAttributeNS` for an attribute with an XML namespace.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Entry {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        String ns = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"; // just a guess
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuildFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuildFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element entry = doc.createElement("entry");
        entry.setAttributeNS(ns, "gd:etag", "*");
        doc.appendChild(entry);
        Element id = doc.createElement("id");
        id.setTextContent("Text");
        entry.appendChild(id);
        printDocument(doc, System.out);
    }

    public static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="*">
    <id>Text</id>
</entry>
```

Replace the namespace URN with the correct one; I just guessed at it based on Googling the `gd:etag` prefix, which brought up some Google Data API and Google Contacts API stuff.

Comment: It's ok. But I don't need the namespace in my XML file. Is this possible to set prefix to attribute without using namespace?

Comment: @Santhosh it's possible, but invalid Namespace constraint. That would break the rest of the toolchain. In other words, yes you do need the namespace in your XML file. You just didn't know you did.

Comment: An XML library isn't going to generate an element or attribute with a prefix without a corresponding xmlns declaration as that's not valid XML. If you generated it yourself, say, simply by concatenating strings, then whatever you send it to would probably choke on it.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you. Can you answer this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932768/put-request-giving-400-bad-request-error

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element element =
    element("entry").attribute("gd:etag", "*")
        .child(element("id").text("Text"));
System.out.println(simple.domToXml(element));
```

Will output:

```
<entry gd:etag="*"><id>Text</id></entry>
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```